# As3 Input field for number to convert to array

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an input field and a list of numbers `(10,43,98,10,45,23,10)`. I want to convert it to an `Array`, so I can use this array for multiple functions.   Please help point me in the right direction.

```
var a:Array = Array[];
a.push(_numInput.text);//this is my input field name
//trace(a);

var l:Number = 0;
for(var i:uint=0; i< a.length; i++)
{
    var t1:Number = l += a[i]; 
    var t2:Number = a.length;   
    var t3:Number = t1 / t2; 
}   

 trace(t3); 
//when i trace the _numInput.text the number show up but i can not use them.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split();` to convert string like this to an array.

```
var a:Array = _numInput.text.split(",");
```

Comment: the only problem  is getting the total of every number in length. i try different ways but i can not make work. i geting

Answer (score 0):

You need to Cast the `String` to an `Integer`!!

```
a.push(int(_numInput.text));
```

Edit:Ups, seems i didn't quite understand the question pre-edit

Answer (score 0):

If you have comma separated numbers in your text field then following is a simplest way to get an `array`,

```
 var str = "10,43,98,10,45,23,10";

 function convertTextFieldStringToArray(s:String):Array
 {
     var a = s.split(",");

     return a;
 }

 trace(convertTextFieldStringToArray(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Spliting a string will just create an array of strings
So what you need to do is then convert that array to an array of int

```
    public function mapIt(obj:Object, index:int, arr:Array):int {
        // validation might be a good idea here since this is user imputed text.
        return int(obj) // convert to int
    }

    // your input string
    var str:String = "10,43,98,10,45,23,10";

    // convert string to array of strings
    var arrayOfStrings:Array = str.split(",")

    trace( typeof arrayOfStrings[0])// verify first element is a string
    trace( arrayOfStrings[0] + arrayOfStrings[0]) // verify string concatination

    var arrayOfInt:Array = arrayOfStrings.map(mapIt) // map each element 
    trace( typeof arrayOfInt[0]) // verify first element is an int
    trace( arrayOfInt[0] + arrayOfInt[0]) // verify numbers are correctly added
```